# Opening shared folders on my network

Tags: networking

I have, in the past been able to set up network shares in Nautilus and could navigate around my shared network folders.

Since Ubuntu 14.04 I set up the network shares in nautilus, and they appear to be shared - but I am prompted for a user name and password to open the shared folders. Except that NO USER NAME OR PASSWORD ARE ACCEPTED!!!!!!

This is irritating in the extreme. I am TRYING to share files between three Ubuntu PCs. This has NEVER been a problem in the past.

How can I access my shared network folders!?! Is this some "improvement" being imposed by the developers...like Unity was? (Unity Sucks btw - I am grateful that I can now get the Mate desktop without having to go to third party sites to get it).

Mike Iott - Ubuntu user since the OS was launched.